# super.onBackPressed(); causes images to come back duplicated because I call it twice. How can I rewrite it to solve this issue?

Tags: java, android, bottomnavigationview, navigationview, onbackpressed

Can someone could tell me how to make this code more efficient and so that `super.onBackpressed();` is only called once.

The problem is that the way I have it now is the only way that it works. The top part of the code is for the `NavigationView`. When the drawer is opened (**if** it is opened) it closes. And the second part is to change the icons in the `BottomNavigationView` to match the fragment that the user is on when they hit the Android back button. The problem with this way is that the images come back duplicated when I hit the Android back button.

I have tried various ways to have only one `super.onBackPressed();`, but as I have mentioned earlier, if I get rid of either one the page doesn't change.

Also tried changing the icons in the `BottomNavigationView` in `onResume();` in the different fragments. But for some reason the app freezes then  and closes.

**How I have it now. Images come back duplicated**

```
 @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        if (mDrawer.isDrawerOpen(GravityCompat.START)) {
            mDrawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
        }
        super.onBackPressed();

        Fragment fragment = getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.fragment_container);
        if (fragment instanceof HomeFragment) {
            mBottomNavigationView.setSelectedItemId(R.id.nav_home);
        } else if (fragment instanceof AttendingEventFragment) {
            mBottomNavigationView.setSelectedItemId(R.id.nav_save);
        } else if (fragment instanceof NotificationsFragment) {
            mBottomNavigationView.setSelectedItemId(R.id.nav_notifications);
        } else if (fragment instanceof ProfileFragment) {
            mBottomNavigationView.setSelectedItemId(R.id.nav_profile);
        }
        super.onBackPressed();
    }
```

**Other ways I have tried to implement the code... Doesn't work...**

```
@Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        Fragment fragment = getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.fragment_container);
        if (mDrawer.isDrawerOpen(GravityCompat.START)) {
            mDrawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
        } else {
            if (fragment instanceof HomeFragment) {
                mBottomNavigationView.setSelectedItemId(R.id.nav_home);
            } else if (fragment instanceof AttendingEventFragment) {
                mBottomNavigationView.setSelectedItemId(R.id.nav_save);
            } else if (fragment instanceof NotificationsFragment) {
                mBottomNavigationView.setSelectedItemId(R.id.nav_notifications);
            } else if (fragment instanceof ProfileFragment) {
                mBottomNavigationView.setSelectedItemId(R.id.nav_profile);
            }
        }
        super.onBackPressed();
    }
```

**onResume() HomeFragment; - Did this for all fragments and app just freezes then closes...**

```
@Override
public void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
        mBottomNavigationView = mActivity.findViewById(R.id.bottomNavigation);
        mBottomNavigationView.setSelectedItemId(R.id.nav_home);
    }

    @Override
    public void onAttach(@NonNull Context context) {
        super.onAttach(context);

        if (context instanceof Activity) {
            mActivity = (Activity) context;
        }
    }
```

**BottomNavigationView**

```
private BottomNavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener navigationItemSelectedListener = menuItem -> {
        switch (menuItem.getItemId()) {
            case R.id.nav_home:
                mSelectedFragment = new TabLayoutFragment();
                break;
            case R.id.nav_notifications:
                seenNotification();
                mSelectedFragment = new NotificationsFragment();
                break;
            case R.id.nav_profile:
                SharedPreferences.Editor editor = getSharedPreferences("PREFS", MODE_PRIVATE).edit();
                editor.putString("profileid", Objects.requireNonNull(FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser()).getUid());
                editor.apply();
                mSelectedFragment = new ProfileFragment();
                break;
            case R.id.nav_save:
                mSelectedFragment = new AttendingEventFragment();
                break;
        }

        if (mSelectedFragment != null) {
            getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.fragment_container, mSelectedFragment, null).addToBackStack(null).commit();
        }

        return true;
    };
```

Comment: Instead of handling this in onBackPressed(), why don't you do this in your fragment's onResume() method ? You could call a method on its parent activity that will update your mBottomNavigationView...

Comment: @matdev I just tried to implement the code in onResume();, but it didn't change the icons of the BNV to match the fragment the user was on... You mind taking a look at the code I just posted to do so and tell me if something is off?

Comment: it seems your nav_home resource is not found in setSelectedItemId(). Can you put a breakpoint inside BottomNavigationView.setSelectedItemId() and see what's happening ?

Comment: @matdev that's not the issue because I have my BNV set up so that by clicking on the icon, it switches, it's like ```case: R.id.nav_home:``` and then the code to switch it, but when I implement the ```onResume();``` it just freezes on the Home page. I can't even click out or anything. It doesn't crash, the app just freezes... Any thoughts? It's only when I implement the onResume(); that this happens... Am I missing something like maybe an ```onPause();```? Is that maybe necessary to call ```onResume();``` later? I don't know...

Comment: do you properly call super.onResume() at the top of your onResume() override ?

Comment: @matdev I just added my BottomNavView code... Maybe it's that... I don't know. Any ideas man?

Comment: When the app freezes, do you see an exception in LogCat ? Instead of re-creating a new instance of Fragment() everytime in your navigationItemSelectedListener, can you re-use the instance previously created ?

Comment: @matdev It just freezes and then the dialog comes up that your app has stopped working, etc... I don't know if onResume(); is a good strategy although I can see why it makes sense. Do you know how to modify my code in onBackPressed();? Maybe I have to remove some fragment if an instance of it is already in the back stack, idk... Or the page just blinks... I checked the Logcat and I'm not getting any exceptions...

Comment: you should see an exception in LogCat. Add several log warning in your onResume() and use logcat to see where you're app is stopping

Comment: @matdev it doesn't even have the chance to execute the onResume() because the app doesn't move past the loading the first page and that's it. Then it blinks and I can't hit the Android back button. It just blinks until I get the message App has stopped working - wait or close app...

Comment: then put a breakpoint in your initial activity's onCreate(), then launch the app in debug mode and execute your code step by step using the F8 button. You'll see where it stops